# Angular 6 CLI not registering service workers

Tags: angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I followed this guide: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

In an existing Angular CLI app I ran

`ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*`

`ng build --prod`

`npm start -c-1 dist/<project-name>`

Chrome Dev tools > Application 
Manifest - detected, no errors or warnings
Service Workers - empty

Network tab loads every file with 200

ngsw-config.json - exists generated by the command
assets/icons - directory generated
app.module.ts - imports array contains `ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })`

Running PWA audit returns an error with ServiceWorker not registered.

Comment: I did notice that executing the same exact steps on a vm running Linux had actually worked and the service worker was registered. Windows seems to be not correctly registering the service worker

Comment: I did the same thing as written in angular docs, and service worker is not registered inside chrome. Don't know how to fix this :/

Comment: have you guys found a solution to this? I have started running out of ideas...

Comment: according to some users in github this is because some 3rd party libraries are changing some application state and it breaks service worker registration

Comment: Any chance you can drop a reference to these discussions?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Adding this to main.ts resolved the problem.

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('ngsw-worker.js');
}
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: thanks! i still don't get why the ServiceWorkerModule does not register the serviceworker even though the functions name is exactly it *facepalm*